# How to make TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() with hangman game go away

Tags: python, while-loop

```
import random

hangmanGame = True
while hangmanGame:
    def wordsPickedBank():
        with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
            allText = file.read()
            words = list(map(str, allText.split()))
            wordsPickedBank(random.choice(words))

    wordPicked = wordsPickedBank()
    word_length = len(wordPicked)
    guesses = str.split("")
```

** Having an error on line 14, can you please help in making this work? I am trying to make the word appear as "_" with the word selected at random from a text file. Can you show how to fix this so that the loop continues without showing the word to the user? **

Comment: The code as shown should file with a ``TypeError`` or ``RecursionError``. ``wordsPickedBank`` calls ``wordsPickedBank`` unconditionally...

Answer (score 1):

Edit your function as follows:

```
while hangmanGame:
    def wordsPickedBank():
        with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
            allText = file.read()
            words = list(map(str, allText.split()))
            return random.choice(words)
```

To return a variable, you have to use the `return` keyword, not the function itself.

Comment: I posted this and then found out this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function you defined (`wordsPickedBank`) isn't returning anything, so it returns None. Which is then passed to `len(wordPicked)`. It's also calling itself with arguments that it doesn't accept (`random.choice(words)`). You gotta fix that function first.